# YouTube Analytics API - How to find viewer demographics of YouTube accounts for all viewers worldwide?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using YouTube Analytics API with oauth2.0 authorization to get channel owner demographic (ageGroup and gender).

It does return values for the ageGroup and gender of the province==US-CA, but I want the filter to output viewer demographics Worldwide. What is the worldwide filter query for YouTube Analytics API?

Here is my code:

`dimensions=ageGroup,gender metrics=viewerPercentage filters=province==US-CA sort=gender,ageGroup`

Answer (score 0):

In the Analytics API, the geographic level of `province` is limited to the U.S. states, either as a dimension or as a filter. Outside the U.S. you can only filter or group by `continent`, `subcontinent`, `country` or `city`. See [Analytics Geographic Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#Geographic_Dimensions)

EDIT:
I've found that you can use the provinces of other countries as defined in [ISO country subdivisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) and filter by `video=={video_id};province=={province_iso_code}`. However, the resulting data mostly doesn't produce consistent results when compared to the totals.